# I can create Flutter new application using VSCode. Now I want to learn Dart programming language

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I want to practice dart , so without losing the flutter project Iam working how can i create dart main file and practice in dart

I did try to create a new dart file in the terminal of the vs code with ,dart create dart_learning - this command and Error: Unable to find git in your PATH this error shown

Answer (score 0):

**Edit for clearing my answare:**

**You do not need git to run Dart projects, but depending on your setup and the requirments for that you might need git.**

The error message you're seeing, "Unable to find git in your PATH," indicates that Dart is unable to locate Git in your system's PATH environment variable.

Here are some steps to get it to work:

Install Git

1. **Install Git**
2. **Check PATH Configuration**: Ensure that Git is correctly added to your system's PATH. To verify this, open your terminal and run the following command to check if Git is recognized.

   ```
   git --version
   ```
3. **Restart VS Code**: After installing Git, it's a good idea to restart Visual Studio Code to make sure it picks up the changes to your system's PATH.
4. Retry Creating the Dart Project:

- Open a terminal in VS Code.
- Navigate to the directory where you want
  to create your Dart project, or use the cd command to change to the
  desired directory.
- Run the following command to create a new Dart
  project

Also make sure you're in the correct directory where you want to create your project.

Comment: why do you need git to execute a dart command

Comment: have you read the error that he get?

Comment: have you read my question? creating a few project files does not need git. maybe it creates a `.gitignore` file but you don't need git for that

Comment: I get it, man. I know that you don't really need git for that, but he received an error related to that, I don't know what setup he/she had and maybe possible need git for that.